# A good jQuery <select> CSS plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I hate the current simple `<select>` drop down menu. Using jQuery, is there a way I can make it more... neat using CSS or something? Like a jQuery form enhancer! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check [jqTransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/)

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you would like? http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 0):

here is something I've used before: http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/